# Problem with inserting user in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I made registration form that will send user's information to a REGISTRATION.PHP which is connected to database and insert user's values in table.However,when I check in phpmyadmin, values are not inserted after refreshing(which is odd because one user is already inserted,I really don't know how).

1. ------>**REGISTRATION.PHP**<------

   ```
           $unosKorisnika=unosKorisnika($ime,$prezime,$mejl,$cryptLozinka);
           if($unosKorisnika)
           {
               $odgovor=['poruka'=>'Uspesan unos'];
               echo json_encode($odgovor);
               http_response_code(201);
           }
   ```

------>**MODELS/FUNCTIONS.PHP**<------

```
function unosKorisnika($ime,$prezime,$mejl,$cryptLozinka){
global $konekcija;
$uloga=1;
$upit="INSERT INTO korisnik(imeKorisnik,prezimeKorisnik,emailKorisnik,lozinkaKorisnik,idUloga) VALUES(:ime,:prezime,:email,:lozinka,:uloga)";
$priprema=$konekcija->prepare($upit);
$priprema->bindParam(':ime',$ime);
$priprema->bindParam(':prezime',$prezime);
$priprema->bindParam(':email',$mejl);
$priprema->bindParam(':lozinka',$cryptLozinka);
$priprema->bindParam(':uloga',$uloga);

$rezultat=$priprema->execute();
return $rezultat;}
```

------>**CONFIG/CONNECTIONS.PHP**<------

```
<?php
define("SERVER","localhost");
define("DB","tech");
define("USER","root");
define("PW","");

try
{
    $konekcija= new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVER.";dbname=".DB.";charset=utf8",USER,PW);
    $konekcija->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $konekcija->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
catch(PDOExceptoin $ex)
{
    echo "Cannot connect to database, ".$ex->getMessage();
}
```

?>

------>**DATABASE**<------

```
CREATE TABLE korisnik ( idKorisnik int(11) NOT NULL,imeKorisnik varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,prezimeKorisnik varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,emailKorisnik varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,lozinkaKorisnik varchar(18) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,datum timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),idUloga int(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is the `INSERT` query called after all? Also, `PDOExceptoin` looks like a typo to me. Did you check whether executing the query throws any exception?

Comment: I called **INSERT INTO** operation in **MODELS/FUNCTIONS.PHP**, but when I want to execute query, it doesn't do anything. Also, I corrected **PDOExceptoin** exception and tried your suggestion to put exception for this query and it says this 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY''

Comment: Well, then the problem is obvious :)

Comment: Indeed it is. I forgot to turn on auto_increment option. Thank you very much Nico!